# How can I filling progressbar by scroll?

Tags: java, android, onfling, onscroll

I want to fill progressbar when I swipe my hand on the phone.
I think I should use scroll method or onfling method. But how can I understand how much I swipe?
I use this code :

```
 @Override
        public   boolean  onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) 
        {       
             try {

                if(e1.getX()-   e2.getX()> min_dist) {

                       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } 
                else  if (e2.getX()- e1.getX()> min_dist  ) {
                          Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
              if(e1.getY() -e2.getY() > min_dist ) {
                         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Swipe up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 } 
              else if (e2.getY()  - e1.getY()> min_dist ) {
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Swipe down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                 }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // nothing
                }

                        return true;
        }
```

But when I swipe my hand x to y it says sometimes `e1.getX() -  e2.getX() = 440` sometimes it says

```
e1.getX() -   e2.getX() =200
```

I do not understand.
and I want to worry can I fill progressbar at the same time swipe?

Comment: Maybe on the on touch metod, on the move,  divide the arg1.getX() to the screen width, now you have the ratio. Set the progressbar value to maximumValue*ratio.

Comment: But how can I set progressbar , it is like that prbar.setvalue=e1.getX() - e2.getX() ; because it is not stabil

Comment: Dont use scroll, use onTouch, at the move case. prbar.setProgress((arg1.getX()/screenWidth)*prbar.getMax());

Comment: @Paul I use your code but progressbar is not filling, I use the toast to make notification at the same time , it says the value is 65 but progressbar is not working